# Can dental scaling cause gum recession?

Tags: dentistry, oral-health, gums

If even forceful brushing which may cause a little bleeding can lead to gum recession, then why not dental scaling, which can often make the whole mouth bloody?

If scaling is done every 6 months (as dentists advise, if I understand correctly), then wouldn't that lead or contribute, to some extent, to gum recession?